# Help on C# DevExpress XtraGrid GridControl - making checkbox in cell invisible

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox, devexpress

I have a GridControl view which is being populated with one column as a Boolean to show the value as a checkbox.

However, I wish to hide some checkboxes based on the state of other columns. I have tried to use the `gridView_CustomDrawCell()` event but cannot find a suitable property.

I expected to find a `visible` property to set to false but there doesn't seem to be one.

Maybe it is possible to hide the checkbox when the view is being populated but I cannot think of one.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to clear the `Graphics` and mark the event as handled :

```
private void gridView_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    if (ConditionIsMet())
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(e.Appearance.BackColor);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work, here's another idea : handle the `CustomRowCellEdit` and `CustomRowCellEditForEditing` events, and remove the editor :

```
private void gridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (ConditionIsMet())
    {
        e.RepositoryItem = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I've been using this product for over 3 years and never realized that you could set `RepositoryItem` to `null`, I've always just created a default item for disabled editors.  This will save me some time!

Comment: @Aaronaught, I don't know if this actually works, it's just a suggestion ;)

Comment: I have tried setting the Repository Item to null but it doesn't work. It uses default editor, probably based on the corresponding property type.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, the e.handled=true method worked. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 4):

What I did for this on a project was to set a RadioGroup as the control with no items so it appeared as blank.

```
private void viewTodoList_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column == CheckMarkColumn)
            {
                if (ConditionIsMet())
                {
                    e.RepositoryItem = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemRadioGroup();
                }
            }
        }
```